# Postgres Import to Google Cloud SQL failing due to missing \N

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds

I am trying to import a dump of my postgres database from AWS RDS into GCP SQL.

I am getting a repeating error that seems to be caused when there is a missing \N from the end of a table row. Example below:

```
2020-10-15 12:52:19 \N  f
```

If I add a \N to the end like so:

```
2020-10-15 12:52:19 \N  f  \N
```

it will work and progress until the next one which could be 500 rows down. The problem is, I have a few million rows. Is there a way I can import without this error occurring or a fix I can put in place?

A find a replace will not work as there is no whitespace after the f so I can't search for the missing version. Also because there is so much data a find crashes the application half the time I carry it out. I am using Atom for looking at the file.

I have also added a screenshot of the Google GUI we are using for importing the file as well as the log error from the dashboard.

[image]

[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Gerard

Comment: So you are import file to an table, would you like to share the table structure. the file is csv file or binary file?

Comment: Hi, 
The file is a sql file eg. database.sql 

I then use the Google Import GUI to import the sql file to the database.

I have just attached another screenshot to the main thread.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is your problem. generally I would do is like trying to replicate it on local postgresql. then If it still not working, then I will try to google. There is some [tips](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/7-best-practice-tips-for-postgresql-bulk-data-loading/) about populate the database

Comment: Ask whomever gave you the file to please fix the problem on their end and send you a new one.